# Python - Changing the length of a list but keeping the sum same

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, size

I'd like to decrease the length of a list (say, from `len(list1) = L` to `len(list2) = M`, where `M<=L`); however, keep the sum of its elements the same.

From the top of my head, I can think of summing random elements in the list until I have the desired list length. However, I can't put it into code. Is there a way you can guide me to? Or can you think of a better way to perform this task?

Note: Ideally, I'd like to also keep the final list's elements between a certain upper bound and a certain lower bound.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your task is no more than your description, I suggest this: remove `L - M` elements and then add the sum of the remove elements to an element in the list. Here's a working example:

```
>>> list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
>>> sum(list1)
55
>>> M = 7
>>> sum_removed = sum(list1[M:])
>>> sum_removed
27
>>> list2 = list1[:M]
>>> list2
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> list[-1] += sum_removed
>>> list2[-1] += sum_removed
>>> list2
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 34]
>>> sum(list2)
55
```

As a function:

```
def truncate_same_sum(lst, truncate_length):
    sum_removed = sum(lst[truncate_length:])
    res = lst[:truncate_length]
    res[-1] += sum_removed
    return res

>>> list1
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> truncate_same_sum(list1, 7)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 34]
```

Answer (score 1):

We can guarantee that M will be greater than zero because the sum of the elements would always be zero.

With that in mind, you can pop two elements from the list and append their sums.

```
a, b = list.pop(), list.pop()
list.append(a + b)
```

If you need list1 and list2 to be different, copy it at the beginning and do this to list2.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should pop the smallest element off the list and then add it to the next smallest.  Something like

```
while len(my_list) > M:
    my_list.sort(reverse=True) #largest to smallest
    x = my_list.pop()
    my_list[-1] += x
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not totally clear, what you want, so there are some options:

if you clear maybe the last 5 elements, these elements have a sum, f.e. 23
All the other elements in the same list, let me say 10, have to become bigger, in the middle: 2.3 each value. Whether you put 2.3 to each value or try to calculate random values with the total sum of 23, that you add - this is your decision.

To hold all the values between boundarys depends on elements, sum and boundaries.

```
def eliminate_elements(my_list, number_of_elements_to_kill):
    len_old = len(my_list)
    len_new = len_old - number_of_elements_to_kill

    sum_rest = 0.
    for element in my_list[-number_of_elements_to_kill:]:
        sum_rest += element

    for i in range(len_new):
        my_list[i] += sum_rest/len_new

    for i in range(len_new,len_old):
        del my_list[len_new]

a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
eliminate_elements(a,2)
print a
```